# I want to call the controller of SpringMVC with Ajax when I click the radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, spring-mvc

For example, if I select radio button 1 and press the submit button, I want to call controller 1, select radio button 2, and press button 2 to call controller 2.

Below is the method I tried. There are two controllers first.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/ynto10", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String ynto10(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {

    String[] columns = req.getParameterValues("chkValue");
    System.out.println(columns.length);
    analyticsService.ynTo10(columns);

    return "redirect:/analytics/info/1";
}


@RequestMapping(value="/nulltoN", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String nulltoN(HttpServletRequest req) {

    String[] columns = req.getParameterValues("chkColnames");
    analyticsService.nullToN(columns);

    return "redirect:/analytics/info/1";
}
```

This is an attempt to call the controller with ajax according to the radio button selection.

```
$('#convert').click(function() {
    var chkVal = [];
    $('input[name=chkColnames]:checked').each(function() {
        chkVal = $(this).val();
    });

        if($('#ynTo10:selected')) {
          $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: 'http://localhost:8080/destiny/ynto10',
              data: {
                  chkValue : chkVal
              },
              dataType: 'json',
              success: alert('변환 OK'),


          })
      }else if($('#nullToN:selected')) {
          $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: 'http://localhost:8080/destiny/nulltoN',
              data: {
                  chkValue : chkVal
              },
              dataType: 'json',
              success: alert('변환 OK'),

          })
      }
```

And I would like to add a checkbox to the variable named chkVal. I would appreciate it if you could give me this part. Have a nice day.

Comment: what errors do you have?

Comment: First, ajax fails to run the controller. And I have to pass the data chkValue and save it in a variable called columns in the controller. Even if I check 3 in the check box, you only enter one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to push the data to the array to get all selected values

```
$('input[name=chkColnames]:checked').each(function() {
        chkVal.push($(this).val());
 });
```

second you can't redirect directly from the ajaxed page,

redirect using js in the success function of your ajax call

```
success: function(data) {
window.location = "/analytics/info/1";
}
```

or better give up on ajax and use a simple get request